# getting 304 response even with django-cors-headers

Tags: django, django-cache, django-cors-headers

I installed `django-cors-headers` in my django application.
I want to display svg file in webbrowser.
For first time, its not loading properly and its showing 304 response in network.

Can anyone help me how to rectify this problem?

Comment: 304 is "Not Modified" and indicates that the resource hasn't changed. This just means that the *If-Modified-Since* timestamp in the request is later than the modification time of the resource. So how is this not intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This response should be fine, it just indicates that your browser has a cached version. It saves Django from having to pass back the response again.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

> **304 Not Modified**
>
> Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match. This means that there is no need to retransmit the resource, since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy.

This sounds like what you are looking for, as the SVG should still be rendered by the browser.